# Can we use descriptive statistics to make inference about the population?

Tags: inference, descriptive-statistics

In the below example we are using sample-mean to make a scientific guess about our population, i.e. using descriptive statistics to make conclusion(or inference) about our population. Is this correct? If not, can someone please explain?

Example:

> We want to study political attitudes in young people. Our population
> is 300,000 undergraduate students.  Because it’s not practical to
> collect data from all of them, we use a sample of 1000 undergraduate
> volunteers from three universities – this is the group who will
> complete our online survey.
>
> In our study of students’ political attitudes, we ask our survey
> participants to rate themselves on  a scale from 1, very liberal, to
> 10, very conservative.
>
> We find that most of our sample identifies as liberal – the mean
> rating on the political attitudes  scale is 3.2.
>
> We can use this statistic, the sample mean of 3.2, to make a
> scientific guess about the population  parameter — that is, to infer
> the mean political attitude rating of all undergraduate students.

Comment: Why not. For everyone's pleasure, I would add a confidence interval.

Comment: Then what is the difference between using descriptive statistics to make conclusion and using inferential statistics to make conclusion? Which will yield a more accurate result?

Comment: Some descriptions are so striking that no formal inference may be necessary. For example Univ A has all 1,2,3 responses and Univ B has all 7,8,9 responses. // However, if A has mean 3.2 and B has mean 3.8 one might want to do formal inference to assess whether the 0.6 difference might be due to sampling error. // Please understand that Likert data are fundamentally ordinal categorical responses, for which medians make sense. But if you look at means you assume data are interval numerical so that addition makes sense. This assumption is controversial; perhaps too often made without thought.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between descriptive statistics and statistical inference is that in the latter case, you are aware of and accounting for the fact that the result you're getting is a random draw from a larger population.

In more concrete terms: a mean value is descriptive of your sample. When you write out the standard error too, it becomes an inference about the larger population.

Answer (score 0):

**Example:** On a Likert-10 scale, you might say responses 5 and 6 are given by people who consider themselves neither strongly liberal nor conservative. Suppose your 1000
observations are as sampled below in R:

```
set.seed(2020)
x = sample(1:10, 1000, rep=T, p = c(3,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,1,1))
```

Numerical descriptions follow: It is clear that the median is 4, the mean a little larger than 4 and the mode (most frequent response) is 2. You could
make a bar plot from the frequencies (perhaps of colors ranging from bright blue through purple to bright red, colors not shown).

Depending on whether you view the
data as ordinal categorical or interval numerical, you might say that the
data are centered at the median or mean, respectively.

```
table(x)
x
  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10 
163 170 154  92 102 114  55  56  43  51 

summary(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  1.000   2.000   4.000   4.257   6.000  10.000 

plot(tabulate(x), type="h", lwd=4, xlab="Opinion", ylab="Frequency", 
     main="n=1000: Opinions (1=Most Liberal)")
 abline(h = seq(40,160, by=20), col="green")
```

[image]

From a nonparametric one-sample Wilcoxon (signed rank) procedure in R, you
might say that the population opinion is represented by median 4 with
a 95% confidence interval $[4.0, 4.5],$ which does not include politically
neutral values 5 and 6.

From the P-value (near 0) you would reject the null hypothesis that the median is 5.5 at the 1% level of significance.

```
wilcox.test(x, mu=5.5, conf.int=T)

        Wilcoxon signed rank test with continuity correction

data:  x
V = 129360, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true location is not equal to 5.5
95 percent confidence interval:
 3.999977 4.499989
sample estimates:
(pseudo)median 
      4.000043
```

If you assume the data to be numerical from a normal population (somewhat
of a stretch), you might use the `t.test` procedure in R. Conclusions would be that the normal population mean is not 4.5 with a 95T confidence interval
$(4.01, 4.42).$

```
t.test(x, mu=5.5)

        One Sample t-test

data:  x
t = -14.75, df = 999, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 5.5
95 percent confidence interval:
  4.091626 4.422374
sample estimates:
mean of x 
    4.257
```